# Matplotlib plotting non uniform data in 3D surface

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to plot a surface from a csv-file and the examples I found here didn't help. In fact, I'm searching for a good chart for my data and, I guess, a surface would be a good idea.
My data-files have the format:

```
 v1_neighbors
 TimeStamp, v2, v3, v4
 1435756244367447, 1, 1, 1
 1435756245460180, 1, 0, 1
 1435756246476204, 1, 0, 1
 1435756247478257, 1, 0, 1
 ...
```

which means that in the instant 1435756245460180 (the second one), node `v1` had as neighbors  nodes `v2` and v4, but not `v3`. This is codified in the 1s and 0s in the data. It is not a deal build a 2D chart for each node with its neighbors but, put all nodes with their neighbors together in one chart became a challenge. What I'm trying to do is a 3D chart with X and Y axes equal to `[v1, v2, v3, v4]` and Z axis equals to the `TimeStamp` then, plot a 3d line for each node (e.g. blue line represents the neighbors of node v1; green line neighbors of node v2, etc.)

Comment: I don't understand how you want to make a surface with that. I will add my interpretation of what you want as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure of understanding your question, but I will show you the solution of my interpretation. First, you need to store the information from your file, in this case I used a numpy array, but it might be better to have a dictionary of numpy arrays... or something better.

I codified the `[v1, v2, v3, v4]` as `[0, 1, 2, 3]`. And each timestamp is just an extra value in the z axis. Then I checked if the value was 0 or 1 to see if you should connect the current node or not.

The code is below

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

timestamps = [r'$t_%i$'%i for i in range(1,5)]

data = np.zeros((4,3,4), dtype=int)
# Data for v1: The data you show
data[:,:,0] = np.array(
    [[1, 1, 1],
     [1, 0, 1],
     [0, 1, 1],
     [0, 0, 1]])

# Data for v2 to v4: random data
np.random.seed(seed=1)
data[:,:,1:] = np.random.randint(0, 2, size=(4, 3, 3))


fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
colors = ['b', 'g', 'r', 'k']

for plane in range(4):
    cols = range(4)
    cols.pop(plane)
    for row in range(4):
        for num_col, col in enumerate(cols):
            if data[row, num_col, plane]==1:
                ax.plot([plane, 3], [0, col], 2*[row], c=colors[plane])

ax.set_xlabel('Initial')
ax.set_ylabel('Final')
ax.set_zlabel('Timestamp')
ax.set_xticks(range(4))
ax.set_yticks(range(4))
ax.set_zticks(range(4))
ax.set_xticklabels([r"$v_1$", r"$v_2$", r"$v_3$", r"$v_4$"])
ax.set_yticklabels([r"$v_1$", r"$v_2$", r"$v_3$", r"$v_4$"])         
ax.set_zticklabels(timestamps)
plt.savefig('plot.png', dpi=300)
plt.show()
```

This gives as plot

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answer @nicoguaro.... and You are right, a surface is not good for these data.. In fact, I didn't realize yet the best way to plot my data. For now, I made a scatter 3D chart. I can't post images, I don't have enough reputation.

Using the code below

```
    ##reading csv file
    df = pd.read_csv('../../Fixed/csv-files/ColumnsZerosAndOnes/V4Neighbors.csv', skiprows=1)
    ## 'cropping' TimeStamp to more simple values
    df['TimeStamp'] = df['TimeStamp'].apply(f)
    ## iteration step calculation
    range_of_time = ((df['TimeStamp'].max() - df['TimeStamp'].min())/time_range)
    ###### coverting initial data into a 3 seconds time-merged data ####
    columns = ['X', 'Y', 'Z']
    df_v4 = pd.DataFrame(data=np.zeros((0,len(columns))), columns=columns)
    base_value = 0
    upper_value = base_value + time_range
    for i in range(range_of_time):
        tmp = df[((df['TimeStamp'] >= base_value) & (df['TimeStamp'] < upper_value))]
        if len(tmp.index) != 0:
                v1_tmp = tmp[tmp['v1'] == 1]
                v2_tmp = tmp[tmp['v2'] == 1]
                v3_tmp = tmp[tmp['v3'] == 1]
                if len(v1_tmp.index) != 0:
                       df_v4 = df_v4.append({'X':node4, 'Y':node1, 'Z':base_value}, ignore_index=True)
                       pass
                if len(v2_tmp.index) != 0:
                       df_v4 = df_v4.append({'X':node4, 'Y':node2, 'Z':base_value}, ignore_index=True)
                       pass
                if len(v3_tmp.index) != 0:
                       df_v4 = df_v4.append({'X':node4, 'Y':node3, 'Z':base_value}, ignore_index=True)
                       pass
                pass
                base_value = upper_value
                upper_value += time_range
        pass

        fig = plt.figure()
        title = fig.suptitle('Emu Fixed Saved Neighbors', fontsize=25)
        title.set_y(0.98)
        fig.set_size_inches(15, 15, forward=True)
        ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

        ## plotting
        ax.scatter(df_v1['X'],df_v1['Y'],df_v1['Z'], c='r', marker='^')
        ax.scatter(df_v2['X'],df_v2['Y'],df_v2['Z'], c='b', marker='o')
        ax.scatter(df_v3['X'],df_v3['Y'],df_v3['Z'], c='g', marker='*')
        ax.scatter(df_v4['X'],df_v4['Y'],df_v4['Z'], c='m', marker='s')

        ## axes labels
        XYLabels = ['','v1','v2','v3','v4']
        Zvalues = df_v1['Z'].unique()
        Zvalues = Zvalues/10000
        ax.set_xticklabels(XYLabels, minor=False)
        ax.set_yticklabels(XYLabels, minor=False)
        ax.set_zticklabels(Zvalues, minor=False)

        # setting axes ticks
        ax.yaxis.set_ticks(np.arange(0, 6, 1))
        ax.xaxis.set_ticks(np.arange(0, 6, 1))

        plt.show()
```

Comment: You can't upload images, but you can link to images stored in other servers, for example. Also, would you mind to complete your code to be executable (I can tell that you are importing ``pandas`` and ``matplotlib``, but they are not there). One last thing, if you can share your data file maybe we can check what you are doing, and help you further.